# GCC cross compiler make vs make all-gcc, why does one give me an error but the other compiles fine?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, gnu-make

I built an i386-elf cross compiler by following [this](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) guide in the osdev wiki, however, before I found that guide, i was attempting to compile (and failing) by simply running `make` after configuring GCC. I kept getting this error 10 or so minutes into the compilation:

```
checking for the value of EOF... configure: error: computing EOF failed
```

However, when I did `make all-gcc` followed by `make all-target-libgcc`, both gcc and libgcc compiled with no errors. Same thing for `make install`, it only worked when i did `make install-target-libgcc` and `make install-gcc`.

Why do I have to compile them separately? And what does the EOF failed error mean?

Comment: If you really want to know, then go look at the `config.log` file and see why the configure script couldn't figure it out.  It doesn't say "EOF failed", it says "_computing_ EOF failed".  The configure script was trying to find the value for the EOF (end of file) setting on this system and it failed to do so, for some reason.